# Understanding Cauchy's mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We studied in class today about the Cauchy's mean value theorem, but in somewhat more complicated version, and i find it difficult to prove. here the theorem:

> Let $f,\ g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a,\ b]$ and differentiable on$(a,\ b)$. Suppose that $f(b) \neq f(a)$.
>   1. **if $g\left(a\right)\ne g\left(b\right)$** so **one** of this things happens:
>      1.1 there is some $x_0\in \left(a,b\right)$ such that $f'\left(x_0\right)\:=\:g'\left(x_0\right)=0$
>   1.2 exist some $c\:\in \left(a,b\right)$ such that $\frac{g'\left(c\right)}{f'\left(c\right)}\:=\:\frac{g\left(b\right)-g\left(a\right)}{f\left(b\right)-f\left(a\right)}$
>   2.**if $g\left(a\right)=g\left(b\right)$** then exist $x_0\in \left(a,b\right)$ such that $g'\left(x_0\right)\:=\:0$

Now, i don't undestand 1.1. from what it derives? What is the magic trick that we need to show here?
2 is just Rolle's theorem, and 1.2 i saw the proof  here [Conditions of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140503/conditions-of-cauchys-mean-value-theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cauchy's mean value theorem states:

> If functions $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on the closed interval
>   $[a,b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, then there
>   exists some $c ∈ (a,b)$ such that the following equation holds:
>
> **A.** $(f(b) - f(a))g'(c) = (g(b) - g(a))f'(c)$

Let's suppose $f(b) \neq f(a)$ and $g(b) \neq g(a)$. So now two cases can be distinguished:

1. $f'(c) = 0$

   Then, since $f(b) \neq f(a)$, it follows from equation **A** that $g'(c) = 0$, so your proposition **1.1** is true.
2. $f'(c) \neq 0$

   Now it's possible to divide both equation **A** members by $f'(c)$, the resulting equation being the one stated in your **1.2** proposition.

This means that, under your hypothesis **1**, it's either the case that proposition **1.1** is true or (inclusive) that proposition **1.2** is true.